# How to tell if USB is connected to android device?

Tags: android

I've written an Android application and I would like the application to be able to recognize when the Android device is plugged into a PC via the USB or even better, know when it is connected and adb logcat is running. Is this possible?

My purpose is to write traces to a separate circular buffer (which would get written to the sdcard occasionally) except when the device is connected e.g., via Eclipse and logcat is running - in that case, I would like to display the traces as part of logcat as they occur.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) doc, you have several intents fired related to USB Storage:

> ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED
>   Broadcast Action: External media is unmounted because it is being shared via USB mass storage.
>
> ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED
>   Broadcast Action: The device has entered USB Mass Storage mode.
>
> ACTION_UMS_DISCONNECTED
>   Broadcast Action: The device has exited USB Mass Storage mode.

You can write a broadcast receiver to know when the device will be connected via USB.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ccheneson. I saw these actions in the intent doc but - to be more specific - I would really like to know whether adb/logcat is running in order to know when to output trace data to logcat instead of a trace file. Is that possible?

Comment: UNfortunately, i have no idea. will think about it